# Script output in terminal differs from MOTD output

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a small script monitor my TLS certificates expiration.

The following is the output when I run `/etc/update-motd.d/05-ssl` in the terminal. The permissions on the script is `633 root`

```
TLS certs             Valid until
● facebook.com    Thu Jun 06 2019
● google.com      Tue Jun 18 2019
```

However when I log in via ssh my MOTD only shows

```
TLS certs        Valid until
```

I suspect this is related to the piping I am doing in the last line when I print the output.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ssl_domains="facebook.com google.com"
currentTime=$(date +%s)
output="TLS certs|      Valid until"

for domain in $ssl_domains; do
    certTime=$(openssl s_client -servername ${domain} -connect ${domain}:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate 2>/dev/null | cut -d= -f2)
    certLineTime=$(date -d "${certTime}" +"%a %b %d %Y")

    certTimestamp=$(date -d "${certTime}" +%s)
    if [ "${certTimestamp}" -ge "${currentTime}" ]; then
        sign="\e[36m●\e[0m"
    else
        sign="\e[1;33m▲\e[0m"
    fi

    output+="\n$sign $domain|  $certLineTime"
done

echo -e "$output" | column -t -s '|'
```

Comment: Are you using a terminal emulator to log in via ssh? PuTTY, etc.?

Comment: What testing have you done? Please make a [mcve].

Comment: I using gnome-termina. I've tried both fish and bash. Works the same in both. My server is running Ubuntu 18.04 btw.

Comment: You could skip building up the variable `output`; just print output as you determine what to print, and pipe the entire `for` loop to `column`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

at the top of your script.

Comment: This worked and MOTD now shows the same as the script output.

Comment: Is this relevant because of OP's special characters?